# Differential backup to a specific date in history

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is that possible to make backup to any specific date in the past in SQL Server?

For example I have full db backup for 15:30, then at 17:30 there were unintended actions on db: is there a way to backup changes made from 15:30 to 16:30?

Comment: The Simple answer is NO.

Comment: This is why log files exist. You can RESTORE to 16:30 if you make a log file backup at any time after 16:30, AND you use full logging. If you use simple logging, you can't do this. So, in a normal deployment on major databases, you will make log file backups every (15 min / 30 min / hour) depending on your tolerance for loss and your activity levels. If the problem was a bad query, you can even take a log backup after the accident, then restore to a specified time. (This doesn't work if the disk broke, though).

Comment: @LaughingVergil, how to perform such restore ? And how to know if the server is configured to make log file backups?

Comment: @M.Ali And the Full answer is MAYBE.

Comment: If this query returns SIMPLE, your pretty much out of luck - select recovery_model_desc from sys.databases where name='<YourDatabase>'

Comment: For first part of your question answer is NO, if you are referring to full backup, for second part Scott has given the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database is configured for `SIMPLE` recover model, you're pretty much out of luck.

If your database is configured for `FULL` recovery model, you might be in luck.  This query will tell you what the recovery model is:

```
select recovery_model_desc from sys.databases where name='<YourDatabase>'
```

If your database is configured for `FULL` recovery, you could attempt to take a transaction log backup ([example here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/8/sql-server-transaction-log-backups/)). Then, you could attempt to restore your full backup `WITH NORECOVERY` and then restore your transaction log backup to a point-in-time using the `STOPAT` option ([example here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/119/sql-server-point-in-time-restore/))

Assuming you can attempt a restore to point-in-time, you should probably restore to a test database to prevent overlaying the current one and then retrieve the missing data from the test database.